# Git Hook - Make server pull after I push to github

Tags: git, github, hook

I have a local repository, and I have set up another repository on my live server:

**www.site.com/projects/ProjectA**

What I want to achieve is very simple: After I PUSH to GitHub, I want the repository at **www.site.com/projects/ProjectA** to PULL - hence update the live version of the project, that my client can see.

I've been reading tons about hooks and I cannot find a very simple example for what I need. All tutorials are made for advanced functionality.

**What I have done**

1. I have the SSH access settings done.
2. I have a remote repository at **www.site.com/projects/ProjectA** that I created while logged in with Putty and doing git clone (at this point my local repo, the GitHub repo and the server repo were all in sync)
3. I copied post-receive.sample from .git/hooks to **www.site.com/projects/ProjectA/**
4. I renamed post-receive.sample to post-receive
5. In github, under the repo settings / webhooks I created a new hook that points to **www.site.com/projects/ProjectA/post-receive**. All other settings I left intact.

I made a local change, commit, push. The Hub updates, the hook shows a new recent delivery. All is well, but the server repository does not update.

The "hook" code is ". /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email" and I don't understand what that does. I looked at other hook samples and I saw some of them have familiar commands like: **exec git update-server-info** so I figured I could write my own command. so I wrote **git pull**, saved it and did the change - commit - push again from my local repo. The result was the same as before. I then tried **exec git pull**. Same thing.

My question is - what am I doing wrong, and the second question is, why the heck isn't there a simple tutorial for this functionality, since this seems to be one of the most usual scenarios. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just saw this unanswered even after years.

Webhooks require you to setup a HTTP POST listener on your server. You can add a http route in your project and perform appropriate pull action.

Reference: [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)

There is an alternate implementation which I use in my projects:

Suppose ~/example is your project public/www folder.
Ssh into your server:

```
$ cd ~/example && mkdir .git && cd .git && git init --bare
$ cat > hooks/post-receive << EOF
> #!/bin/sh
> GIT_WORK_TREE=~/example git checkout -f
> EOF
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

The above will create a bare git repo in `~/example/.git` folder. Add a post-receive executable hook and perform checkout into the example directory.

On local repo:

```
$ git remote add server ssh://my_user@my_server.com:/absolute_path/example/.git/
$ git push server +master:refs/heads/master
```

This works well for me. I can push, revert commits whenever I need.

Reference: [Server repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)

Comment: But i will have to push 2 times? One to github and another one to the server?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want the repository on your server to pull, after you pushed to GitHub.

So you have to notify your server to pull, after you pushed from your local repository.
The post-receive-hook on the server is not, what does that. It is called, after something is received, but the push to github does not make the server receive anything.
(See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

To notify the server, I would use the "post-update" hook on the remote repository. But as your remote is on GitHub, that could be a problem. As I am no GitHub-user I do not exactly know how to do that. Try "Webhook" or "Services" in the settings-tab of your repository (if you own the repository).

If hooks on GitHup do not do the trick:

As you suggested, you have ssh-access on your server, I think, it is some kind of linux. Then you could just write a small script that updates the server-repo, place it on the server and execute it via ssh after every push.
I am not aware of any hook that gets called on the local repo after a push, so perhaps, you should write another script, that does the push and invokes the ssh-command, if the push was successful.
If you use linux-systems, I can help you with the scripts.

What you are doing with the post-receive-hook on the server is, that git pull is executed, after you pushed to the server, but you are pushing to GitHub.

I hope this explains why your approach is not working.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I hope there's a solution, because it seems fairly simple. I can log on with ssh and do git pull from the server every time, but that's annoying and not all participants in the project have access to the server, so I would have to do it everytime they push something, so that's not an option.

Comment: Well, if there are multiple persons on the project, any solution based on their local repos are not practicable. In this case, you have to use a hook on the remote repo. Did you try webhooks?

Comment: I did some googleing on webhooks. It looks like you have to run a web-server to receive the message and then pull on the server. This should not be too hard. See the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/) and write a php-script, that pulls the repo. That should be a script of about 5 to 10 lines.
It seems there is no other possibility.

Comment: I'll do some more reading. It should not be that difficult. I don't know why there isn't a more straightforward way of doing it. Thank you for your help

Comment: LTTP, but this is the job of a CI server, simple as it is. Configuring a POST endpoint with some shell code is the "roll your own CI" version, which is why it doesn't seem straightforward. Setting up Jenkins or Teamcity or whatever to do this one thing would feel overkill, but it is the "standard" approach. The expectation is that you'd learn to use it for lots of other automation as well as the project grows. But if this is the only automation you'll ever need, yeah, BYO POST endpoint.