# How to get git mirror to keep updated continually?

Tags: git, backup, mirroring, git-bare

I want to back up my git master, which is set as bare as per the documentation. The git master is set up on a VM on premise.

However I need to back up the master as it's a busy team and a large team, so if anything does go wrong with master we want to be back up as soon as possible without having to make sure no-one pulls before everyone has pushed (large team). I understand that mirroring will clone everything including all the refs etc, but what is the best way to keep the mirror in step with the main master?

Comment: This depends on where your repo is hosted.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated accordingly.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but check out "Server-Side Hooks" on the [Git Hooks Docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (right at the bottom).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Hook - Make server pull after I push to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382150/git-hook-make-server-pull-after-i-push-to-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25815131/7976758